# Apache: one domain - multiple folders with different certificates

Tags: apache, ssl, nginx, https

I've just started my linux security classes and my task is to set up an apache2 server (nginx is allowed aswell but chose the first one) with configuration listed below:

There is one domain (localhost) with different subfolders:

- /ssl (any user can access, force redirect to https)
- /ssl/user_1 (access with certificate "user_1")
- /ssl/user_2 (access with certificate "user_2")
- /ssl/any (access with any certificate (user_1, user_2))
- /no_ssl (access without certificate)

I don't have much experience with apache2 but succesfully managed to set it up and configured basic ssl. However, I managed to set just one certificate for all folders/subfolders - I've been digging through whole Google (I have three pages of results marked already as visited..) but could not find a proper solution, tutorial or docs how to set up few different certificates, each for a different folder. I found few but it's often the case that the code was written few years ago and does not work anymore in the new version.

I'm not asking for a full solution but I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction or provide some good tutorials/docs about the matter. Some configuration snippets would be awesome aswell of course!

Thank you so much in advance,
F.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I'm giving too much away when I say you are misunderstanding that part of the question. You are assuming that user_1 and user_2 are server certificates.

This is about client certificates - otherwise options 1 and 4 are the same. Also I think this is implied with the certs being user_1 and user_2 rather than server_1 and server_2. So go read up about client certificates.

Saying that I still don't know how to do this simply for options 2 and 3 so it's still a tricky question. Let us know how this is done after the assignment is finished for my own curiosity and good luck figuring it out yourself!